# Would society become matriarchal, patriarchal or balanced if the military consisted mostly of women but the top leadership are men?

Tags: society, science-fiction, space, military

The premise is that in this world, mankind has extended their territory throughout the solar system. We now have colonies on multiple moons and planets. War and combat between the different factions now focuses primarily on spaceship battles.

New technology has been developed to enable mankind to remotely control these huge spaceships through thoughts. Thus, war ships are now unmanned and controlled solely through this "psychic" link. But, the catch is that only women are able to operate the technology. So for example: one female officer would mentally control a squadron of 100 small fighters whereas a more experienced and talented one would be capable of "piloting" several large battleships that require greater mental strength.

An admiral would be appointed to coordinate and give tactical orders to these female officers. They would be in charge of strategy and fleet decisions. They would be trained in an academy and would be selected purely on merit regardless of gender. However, admirals still consist of 85% males due to the fact that strategically gifted female officers would also be excellent at controlling large and complex battleships and it would be a waste to let them be admirals as such talent is quite rare.

In this world, would society treat men and women differently? Or would such a military system make people treat both sexes "more" equally compared to our own? Would sexual discrimination be common in the military?

Edit: The ships are controlled through thoughts via some sort of module between the brain and the ships. Women are the only ones able to operate such a module. I'm still working on the logic on why such a module only works with women. This system is much better than remote controls etc as this system enable a single person to control hundreds of ships at once with just their thoughts.

Comment: With Australia adopting a 75% female quota for all future Defence hires, we'll let you know a real world answer in about a decade...

Comment: Given that in your world, upper management is still 85% male, would it not make sense that its still a patriarchal society? Given the scale of the human population as it is, it makes no sense that women are too important to move into admiral positions. It also makes no sense that only women can control spaceships. Obviously someone must have built the spaceship and its control system. Why can only women control it remotely and why have people forgot about remote controllers?

Comment: @Shadowzee I have edited my post. Hopefully it clarifies the last portion of your reply. And I want my world where admirals are largely men but I still have not figured out a solid logic why such a thing would happen even if most of the military are females.

Comment: So you can control the spaceships but who is fighting on the ground or in space? Drone operators is something that can be done by women in RL too, as it doesn’t require the to go into the field where woman are still a minority for several reasons.

Comment: I don't know if this question needs an answer to this question, but you may want to think about it for your world: are the women commanding the ships in a position to die if the fleet is overrun?  Much of how our military operates is built around the reality that the soldiers have skin in the game -- their lives.  Things shift if there is only materiel at stake.

Comment: Clearly the "psychic link" only works for women because they are the only ones that produce the correct agendon particles.  Women produce E-type agenda (the plural of agendon) and men produce T-type agenda.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how any answer to this could be anything but entirely opinion based. The prevailing structure and ethos in your society would surely be echoed in it's differentiated parts (such as the military). You haven't told us about how your society works. There are more controversial issues such as the relative flatness of normalised intelligence measures as they are related to the genders, and strategic thinking, which is related to the historic (genetic) adaptation of the male to hunting and mating behaviour. Please [edit] to clarify. Meanwhile voting to close as POB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if the military here works like the current American military (voluntary sign-up, no draft), you're probably looking at a society *extremely* stratified by gender. Almost insanely so.

[Okay, full disclosure, this post is based on things I've read and soldiers and ex-soldiers I personally have spoken to. Considering I have everything second-hand, I admit that I may be unable to take all factors into account. That said, let's try this thing.]

The most common reason for soldiers to sign up for the military--barring the draft--is poverty. These days people are often looking for money for school or a skillset to get them out of a dead-end life. The amount of soldiers just looking for help to pay for college is statistically *huge*. Visiting foreign places is pretty big, but that is also often tinged with "Get me out of this dead end burg." For some it's a family business, but again, trace it back far enough and, barring being drafted, that first one to join was often escaping poverty.

This isn't everyone, of course, but it's enough to see some distinct cultural trends in our own society, and it's not rare. Look around enough and you'll find poverty has been a factor with military service pretty much through all of known history.

Now lets look at your military.

Assuming it works the same--voluntary sign up--that seems to argue that people, *female* people especially, are looking to escape impoverished or dead end lives. If it's poverty, what in your society is causing a significant number of a *specific gender* to be poor? If a dead end life, what would be influencing these women--if it *wasn't* money--that would make them want to use the military as a way out?

This is telling enough, but let's look at our modern day military again.

One of the problems with the modern military is degrees. Many poorer soldiers have trouble getting into high ranked positions without them. This is a bit cruel, as many soldiers get into the military and dedicate their lives to it, only to find a glass ceiling because they were so busy being *loyal* they didn't take time off to go to college. One could also argue that, even without a degree, they'd do better in those high ranked positions due to their vast experience, but there still seems to be prejudice against them. Worse, it means they're barred from some of the most highly paid positions, keeping them in the very cycle of poverty they used the military to escape.

Now your military.

You have highly competent female soldiers who can do the job of high ranking officers. Instead, they're barred from those jobs completely due to a glass ceiling; those prestigious, top paying jobs are being reserved for men.

Again, this comes with societal implications, and those implications keep coming back to women being respected less, being valued less, being always kept apart from men. The fact that mostly guys are in charge turns this very much into a Patriarchal society--a Patriarchy doesn't need to have women be meek and in the kitchen, it only needs to see them as lesser than men *no matter what they accomplish* and seek to keep them less powerful than men. Your military is doing just that.

The thing is, women are joining anyway, which once again implies they're finding something there they wouldn't by taking another route in life. Maybe, even though they don't receive respect from higher ups in the military, just having joined gives them more respect than they would have at home. Again, it feels indicative that women *know* about the glass ceiling and flock to the military anyway because back home is worse.

Also, this:

> "However, admirals still consist of 85% males due to the fact that
>   strategically gifted female officers would also be excellent at
>   controlling large and complex battleships and it would be a waste to
>   let them be admirals as such talent is quite rare."

If your women are not somehow genetically modified for this to be true, this smacks of a society assuming certain traits are found more strongly in certain genders, then *making that true*.

For instance, because it's assumed that girls are bad at math, teachers are less likely to call on girls in class or give them the best help when they have questions. Studies have proven this. The teachers aren't being malicious, this is an unconscious response to the fact that "everyone knows" girls are bad at math.

Women in more professional settings are also less likely to be forgiven simple mistakes than men, and to be looked on less favorably as a whole. They have to be twice as perfect and accomplished to get the same job as a guy. It's like they're being punished for trying to buck a system "everybody knows" to be true, but again, no one is being malicious. For those in charge, this is just an unconscious response to a lifetime of being told a "truth" that has about as much traction as "All Jewish people are good with money" or "All Asians are highly intelligent."

And, of course, all of this affects women's relationship with math and desire to learn it, exacerbating the problem. We *make it true.*

So here are your women, being shunted into jobs it's assumed they can do better than men, but with no scientifically verifiable physical or mental reason this is so. It smacks of "truthiness," an assumed truth that is not at all true when looked at closely. It definitely reeks of very solid cultural ideas that certain traits are more natural on one gender than in the other. They just have "skilled at piloting a battleship" as one of the traits coded female.

So, yeah, society would almost *have* to be treating men and women differently, and in fact it's likely that they're treating women *worse* than your modern American woman gets treated. Something to think about anyway, if this wasn't what you were going for.

Comment: thanks! was looking for this type of answers!

Answer (score 1):

Here are my 2 cents...

Fighting space battles is one thing. Owning the land is another. So the question is what role would men play in your world?

It seems plausible to me that in a world where woman dominate the field their social status will greatly improve. But to make this a matriarchal world it will eventually also require social engineering to let people accept this as a norm that women are above men in some way. For example:

1. Religion
2. Political Ideology
3. Birth quota might also have an effect

(Same can be applied for men)

Another question is to what extend men play still a role in the military or other professions. Men could:

1. Fight on the ground
2. Be scientist to create new weapons
3. Build ships
4. Be in a commanding position

The result might be that men are seen as incapable to fly the ships, but necessary to make it happen and hence smarter. Smarter maybe to command the fleets? This might especially a thing if women are only thought to be good enough to fly ships and incapable to do anything else. A lot of this will depend on how your society evolved. The fact that woman only can control those ships might not be the key factor for the social structure in place.

So I think it’s hard to tell just from the fact that women fly space ships, whether or not the system is grown to be more matriarchal or patriarchal as other factors could have led to the existing social structure.

Answer (score 1):

Matriarchal society is not a "gender-bender" patriarchal one. It has a very special social structure. For matriarchal society the main focus is on raising children, not on war of any kind.

This is exactly why it apperas and develops: if child surviving (not birth!) rates drops far bellow of what is needed to sustain population, mothers needs became defining for society. Mothers become those who sets priorites and gives orders. If not - population just dies out.

So it has nothing to do with female role at war and "power" they have. "Ballanced" is most suitable answer for your question.

You may have a matriarchy in your setting. For this you need sort of enemy biological weapon that hit all the humanity and that makes children extreamly fragil and prone to sudden death (like you know "there are to many of you and you spead too fast"), with survival rates without very special and expensive care about 1 out of 20.

Comment: Can you support evidence for that claim that a matriarchal society would be one striving for peace. It certainly can understand the importance of woman bearing child’s, but neither is a patriarchal society focused on providing sperm. I doubt there is a clean cut definition just as that.

Comment: It is not the "one striving for peace". It just trying to survive.  Matriarchal society can even be more aggresive to neighbors then patriarchal one ("they have food for our children! Bring it to us!"). Human males  just less care about  siblings than females do. And do not mess bearing a child and birth (0.75y) with far more complex process of raising it (12-15y).

Comment: Than simply add an outer factor to the mix of his story making humanity strive for survival and there you go. That said all what you brought on sounds logical but I doubt that there is much basis for that claim to be based in hard facts. I’m not and archeologist nor do I study social structures. I can only look at wiki atm and find that a lot of early history where this might have played a role is only a hypothesis.